# Iterators invalidation

Tags: c++, while-loop, iterator, erase

Hi I read in C++ primer that adding elements to a vector invalidates the iterators. I don't understand why deleting elements doesn't invalidate them as the following code works

```
std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

auto b = a.begin();

while (b != a.end()){
    
    if (*b%2 != 0)
        a.erase(b);
    else
        b++;
}
```

NOTE: This code if from C++ primer itself and [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) as well

Comment: `b` is inalidated after `erase` and therefore this is **UB**. Anything can happen and even if it works it doesn't mean it's valid.

Comment: Just because some code seems to work doesn't mean it's without errors. *Undefined behavior* can unfortunately often seem to "work".

Comment: [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) _"...invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator...."_.  _"invalidates"_ means that the code should not use them and if it does then it gets Undefined Behaviour.  Undefined Behaviour includes appearing to work.

Comment: To solve your problem, you need to use the iterator that [`erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) *returns*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the link https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase also has the same code

Comment: @ArkanSaaS not its not the same code. The example has `it = c.erase(it);`

Comment: @ArkanSaaS *Almost* the same code, but it does (using your code) `b = a.erase(b)`. The difference is the assignment.

Comment: you cannot proove presence or absence of undefined behavior by running code and looking at the result. You can cross a red traffic light without being hit by a car, but that doesnt make it legal nor does it imply that you will never be hit by a car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this code snippet

```
auto b = a.begin();

while (b != a.end()){
    
    if (*b%2 != 0)
        a.erase(b);
    else
        b++;
}
```

is invalid. It works because the container std::vector satisfies  the concept of contiguous ranges. If instead of the vector you will use for example `std::list<int>` when the iterator `b` will be invalid.

It would be correctly to write

```
auto b = a.begin();

while (b != a.end()){
    
    if (*b%2 != 0)
        b = a.erase(b);
    else
        b++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not actually an answer to the question, but I think it is worth mentioning that in modern C++ you should try to avoid iterators by using algorithms and range-based for loops. In this particular case use [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2):

```
std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
std::erase_if(a, [](int x) { return x%2 != 0; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Common idiom. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase): (erase) 'Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator.

Others have pointed out it should be written like this:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); )
{
    if (*it % 2 != 0)
    {
        it = vec.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
       ++it;
    }
}
```

Adjust if one prefers 'while' over 'for'. If performance is paramount one can start from the end though this may be less cache friendly.

Edit: code snippet is literally the cppreference link.

Answer (score 0):

Adding elements to a vector may lead to a complete reallocation of the vector.
This invalidates all iterators held previously.

If you delete an entry of the vector the erase method returns:
a) a iterator to the next valid element
b) the end iterator.

But you have to use it. In your case:

```
b = a.erase(b);
```

Comment: But what happens when an element is deleted in between, how is the contiguity of data maintained ?

Comment: Its maintained by moving (https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)

This effectively reduces the container size by the number of elements removed, which are destroyed.

Because vectors use an array as their underlying storage, erasing elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container to relocate all the elements after the segment erased to their new positions. 

So every entry after the deleted element gets moved.

Comment: Be aware that the example of cpprefence also does  it = v.erase(it); in comparison to your or original source code

Answer (score 0):

As many pointed out it works by chance. Do not do this in prod.
Iterators are designed to be as lightweight as possible so there won't be a flag saying it's invalid. That would be too wasteful.

std::vector iterator is probably implemented as a pointer with some helper functions. Removing one element will shift everything so that same pointer now points to the new element where the old one used to be. It only works because elements are stored in contiguous memory without gaps.